# Invariable Segfault while trying to access object in h5py.Dataset

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I was wondering if there were any particular restrictions on accessing data via h5py? I'm expecting an array with internal arrays from the dataset in question.

I can load the object into memory, access most of the keys within the datafile.

```
>>> import h5py

>>> fileobj = h5py.File('path/to/file.ext')
>>> test = fileobj['SomeKey']
>>> test.dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> test[:]
array([  3.50000460e+02,   1.23662217e-03,   1.23662872e-03, ...,
     9.94521356e-03,   9.94531916e-03,   9.94542476e-03])
>>> test.shape
(49682960,)
>>> # this loads fine
... problem = fileobj['SomeOtherKey']
>>> problem.shape
(13570,)
>>> # accessing specific keys works fine too
... sub_dset = problem['subkey1']
>>> sub_dset.dtype
dtype('O')
# checking compression, nothing out of the ordinary...
>>> problem._filters
{'gzip': 1, 'shuffle': (144,)}
>>> problem.dtype['subkey2']
dtype('O')
>>> problem['subkey2']
Segmentation fault
```

This also occurs when I try slices, copying datasets, etc.

```
>>> problem['subkey2'][:]
Segmentation fault

>>> problem['subkey2']
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.zeros(problem.shape)
>>> # this works fine
... ds = fileobj.create_dataset('ds', data=problem['subkey1'])
>>> # this also works fine
... ds1 = f.create_dataset('ds1', problem.shape, problem.dtype, data=problem['subkey1'])
>>> # however.....
... ds2 = f.create_dataset('ds2', problem.shape, problem.dtype, data=problem)
Segmentation Fault
>>> ds = f.create_dataset('ds2', data=problem['subkey2'])
Segmentation Fault
```

At first I thought this might be a memory issue. However, I tested it with a standard file used as a test (now-deprecated, I believe) library:

https://github.com/jmchilton/pymz5/blob/master/test_data/test.mz5

In this case, the issue reproduces with the following example:

```
>>> fileobj = h5py.File('test.mz5')
>>> problem = fileobj['SpectrumMetaData']
>>> problem.shape
(26,)
>>> problem['precursors']
Segmentation Fault
```

I've checked, and the 'id' (among other keys) for the SpectrumMetaData Datasets are fine, and this example has no compression filters, suggesting the segmentation fault is caused by the data itself.

Just in case this is Python-version or h5py-specific, I had run all the previous tests on an h5py version 2.5.0 with Python 2.7.9.

When I try it on h5py version 2.2.1 (Ubuntu, Python 3.4.3), I get:

```
TypeError: No NumPy equivalent for TypeVlenID exists
```

I know that variable length dtype support was improved in h5py after [version 2.3](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/special.html), so I upgraded to h5py 2.5.0 on Python 3, and get the same issues as before.

Any way to access this data using h5py with the higher level API? I'd rather not wade in building a custom data type in Cython, if possible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug, maybe related [to this?](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/623) A possible work around maybe to use the low-level API to get the dtypes of the parts (using `prob_type = problem.id.get_type()` and `prob_type.get_member_type()`), and construct a new dtype, replacing the vlen parts with fixed size equivalents.